# Trying to add a line break to function, but can't get it to work correctly

Tags: r

I'm brand new to R so bear with me! Trying to do a project for a college class.

Here is my function:

```
function(x) {
    y = seq(from = 1, to = x, by = 1)
    f = cat(paste("This is Banana", y, sep="\n"))
    return(f)
}
```

From some searching on here I learned to add `cat` and `sep="\n"` to insert line breaks. However it is inserting them in the wrong place:

When I run the function (ex. `x=3`) it does this and skips the number to the next line

```
This is Banana
1 This is Banana
2 This is Banana
3 NULL
```

I want it to look like this:

```
This is Banana 1
This is Banana 2
This is Banana 3
```

Any advice is appreciated, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of `f` and move the closing paren for `paste` (you can also simplify `seq`):

```
myfun <- function(x) {
    y <- seq(x)
    cat(paste("This is Banana", y), sep="\n")
}

myfun(3)
This is banana 1 
This is banana 2 
This is banana 3
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Didn't know you could run a function without using return

Answer (score 3):

Dan Y already answered your question, I just want to mention why your code is giving a different output - it's because the `paste` function uses the `sep` argument to decide the character string used to separate each given argument, not just add it once at the end of all the arguments given.

So `paste("This is Banana", y, sep="\n")` is actually inserting the line break between `This is Banana` and `y`, which is why the numbers appear on the next line instead of the current one.

Comment: Nice addition, I'll throw some points your way with an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, greatly appreciated